# Calculate percentage of the total in qlik sense

Tags: qlikview, qliksense

I have the following data structure in my qlik sense desktop (version june 2019):

```
Time           Reference    Relevant
01.01.2019      1            1
01.01.2019      2            0
01.02.2019      3            0
01.02.2019      4            0
```

And I want to built a line chart, which displays the %-of the Total occuring references per day.

So the values would be:

```
01.01.2019    0.5
01.02.2019    0
```

What do I have to write in the formel editor? The expression: `Sum(total [Relevant])/Count(total [Reference])`is not working.

What is the trick to combine a sum and count with respect to the date?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the count of References that have Relevant=1 you can do `Count({<Relevant={1}>}Reference)` so then you can do a percentage as `Count({<Relevant={1}>}Reference)/Count(Reference)`.

However since the data in your scenario is very simple, you could actually just do `sum(Relevant)/count(Reference)` - no need for the total as you're not including the Reference in the second table.

If you did want a table to show what % that day was relevant whilst still showing the Reference then you'd probably want something more like `Count(TOTAL<Time> {<Relevant={1}>}Reference)/Count(TOTAL<Time> Reference)` or just `sum(TOTAL<Time> Relevant)/count(TOTAL<Time> Reference)` in your simple scenario.